# Create text file failed, error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, fopen

I tried to create file on my xampp directory :

```
path : D:\ProgramFile\xampp\htdocs\pg_api
```

I already created one php file, `create.php`

This is the code :

```php
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I ran the code and the file generated successfully, now what I want is to create a text file with name from variable :

This is what I tried :

```php
<?php

$currentdate = date('d/m/Y_H:i:s');
$id = 1;
$filename = "id_".$id."_".$currentdate.".txt";

$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

I expected the file to be created with `$filename` as file name but an error on the browser page says:

> Warning: fopen(id_1_29/10/2019_05:59:57.txt): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   D:\ProgramFile\xampp\htdocs\pg_api\create_1.php

(My error : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zxrL.jpg))

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: i would imagine it is interpretting `/` as a directory separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows do not allow special characters like `/`as a filename (it is not safe even in linux). Not just that, i will rather go with file name like `id_1_29-10-2019_05-59-57.txt`

To achieve the above filename:

```
$currentdate = date('d-m-Y_H-i-s');
$id = 1;
$filename = "id_".$id."_".$currentdate.".txt";

$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: your answer is correct my code, i didnt know about special character  before, now i know it, thank you very much Gabriel